# Add a route to virtual machine on a different computer

Tags: networking, route

I'd like to add a route from my computer to a VMWare Virtual Machine which runs on a computer in a different office. I can access the host computer (192.168.110.164) where the machine is running on a virtual subnet. The IP address of the virtual computer I'd like to connect to is 192.168.44.4 (I MUST NOT change it due to some third party software running on it which would need to be configured again by Third Party when the IP address is changed).
I know that there is a "route add" command, but because I do not know anything about routes and metrics, I fail to understand the examples given on some web pages. I tried a "route ADD 192.168.44.0 MASK 255.255.255.0 192.168.110.164", but that seems not work (I cannot ping it from my computer, only from the host).
How do I add that route? Thanks a lot for your hints.

Comment: Can you ping that virtual machine from the host server? If so the command you used should be fine, however you may need to enable ip forwarding on the host machine.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are geographically separated from your "other office" where the machine is, at first blush it seems like you are trying to connect to a machine that you don't have a direct route to. You can import your environment (unchanged) to a Skytap configuration, assign a public IP and then easily connect to it from your machine.  Check us out at http://www.skytap.com/blogcomments

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found a simpler solution: since the machine I want to connect to is a Virtual Machine, I could add a second network card, and then the machine had an IP address in the "normal" subnet also.